# Filter a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, sub-array

I want to have a sub array (between min and max) of a numpy 2D ndarray

```
    xy_dat = get_xydata()
    x_displayed = xy_dat[((xy_dat > min) & (xy_dat < max))]
```

min and max are float in order to be compare with the first value of the array xy_dat

xy_dat is a 2D numpy array :

```
[[ 735964.            1020.        ]
 [ 735964.04166667    1020.        ]
 [ 735964.08333333    1020.        ]
 ..., 
 [ 736613.39722222    1095.        ]
 [ 736613.40416667    1100.        ]
 [ 736613.41111111    1105.        ]]
```

x_displayed is correctly filtered but I have lost the second value (it is now a 1D array) :

```
[ 735964.04166667  735964.08333333  735964.125      
 ...,  
736613.39027778  736613.39722222  736613.40416667]
```

How make the filter on the first value and keep the other ?

Comment: That's because your comparison is not 2D. For example what does it mean is you have two numbers in one row and one is inside your range and one is not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should perform the condition only over the *first* column:

```
x_displayed = xy_dat[((xy_dat[:,0] > min) & (xy_dat[:,0] < max))]
```

What we do here is constructing a view where we only take into account the first column with `xy_dat[:,0]`. By now checking if this 1d is between bounds, we construct a *1D* boolean array of the rows we should retain, and now we make a selection of these rows by using it as item in the `xy_dat[..]` parameter.

Comment: `[:,0]` means through all the first array, with only the first element of the second one ? Didn't know, that's neat !

Comment: @IMCoins: it means the first column of every row yes :)

Comment: Oh right, it only works with numpy.arrays. I tried it on some python arrays, and some incredible sadness came into my eyes. :'(

Comment: @IMCoins You can always subclass lists and overload `__getitem__` yourself :)

Comment: @IMCoins: well we can construct a subclass of the Python vanilla lists to let it work with lists as well. A possible problem however is that in Python items can be hybrid and the sublists can have different size. So how would you work with `[1, [], [14], 'ab']`? Simply ignore non-sublists and empty lists?